# How to handle padding when reading in a BMP?

Tags: c, image, bmp

I am trying to read in a BMP file using C and to generate a grayscale version of that image. However, I do not know how to handle the padding of rows.  (Recall that the size of each row in bytes has to be a multiple of 4.) When I move 3 bytes per step in each row, how can I then stop before the padded bytes? The critical part of my code is:

```
  byte pixel[bytes_per_pixel];
  for (int i = height - 1; i > 0; i = i - 1)
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j = j + 1)
      {
        fread(pixel, 3, 1, image);           // What to do with the padding?
        int gray_scale_value = grayScaleConversion(pixel);
        converted_image[i][j] = gray_scale_value;
      }
```

For the sake of completeness, here is what I've got so far and you can find a reference image below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define HEADER_LOCATION 0x0000
#define WIDTH_LOCATION 0x0012
#define HEIGHT_LOCATION 0x0016
#define BITS_PER_PIXEL_LOCATION 0x001C


typedef short i16;                            // integers with 16 bits
typedef unsigned int i32;                     // integers with 32 bits
typedef unsigned char byte;


void printMatrix(int rows, int columns, int matrix[rows][columns])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i = i + 1)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; j = j + 1)
        printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);

      printf("\n");
    }

  printf("\n");
}

int grayScaleConversion(byte pixel[3])
{
  unsigned char gray_scale_value = (int) (pixel[0] * 0.0722 + pixel[1] * 0.7152 + pixel[2] * 0.2126);
  return gray_scale_value;
}

int read_bmp_header(const char* file_name, int* image_header, int* image_height, int* image_width)
{
      // Here we open the given file for reading in binary mode.
      FILE* image = fopen(file_name, "rb");

      // Here we check whether opening the given file was successful.
      if (!image)
        {
          printf("Invalid File\n");
          return -1;
        }
      else
        {
          i32 header;  // should be "BM" (or "4D 42" in hex)
          i32 height;
          i32 width;

          // Here we read in the header of the given BM image.
          fseek(image, HEADER_LOCATION, SEEK_SET);
          fread(&header, 2, 1, image);
          *image_header = header;
          // Here we read in the height of the given BM image.
          fseek(image, HEIGHT_LOCATION, SEEK_SET);
          fread(&height, 4, 1, image);
          *image_height = height;
          // Here we read in the width of the given BM image.
          fseek(image, WIDTH_LOCATION, SEEK_SET);
          fread(&width, 4, 1, image);
          *image_width = width;
          return 0;
        }
}


void read_bmp_data(const char* file_name, int height, int width, int converted_image[height][width])
{
      FILE* image = fopen(file_name, "rb");
      // Here we read in the number of bits per pixel in the given BM image.
      i16 bits_per_pixel;
      fseek(image, BITS_PER_PIXEL_LOCATION, SEEK_SET);
      fread(&bits_per_pixel, 2, 1, image);
      // Here we compute the number of bytes per pixel in the given BM image.
      i32 bytes_per_pixel = ((i32) bits_per_pixel) / 8;
      // Here we initialise the converted image.
      byte pixel[bytes_per_pixel];
      for (int i = height - 1; i > 0; i = i - 1)
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j = j + 1)
          {
            fread(pixel, 3, 1, image);                      // What to do with the padding?
            int gray_scale_value = grayScaleConversion(pixel);
            converted_image[i][j] = gray_scale_value;
          }
      fclose(image);
}

int main()
{
  int image_header;
  int image_width;
  int image_height;
  read_bmp_header("img.bmp", &image_header, &image_height, &image_width);

  // Some prints to see the collected data.
  printf("Size of int16 in byte = %llu \n", sizeof(i16));
  printf("Size of int32 in byte = %llu \n", sizeof(i32));
  printf("Size of byte in byte = %llu \n", sizeof(byte));
  printf("header (in hex) = %x \n", image_header);
  printf("width (in bytes) = %u \n", image_header);
  printf("height (in bytes) = %u \n", image_header);


  int grayed_image[image_height][image_width];
  read_bmp_data("img.bmp", image_height, image_width, grayed_image);
  printMatrix(image_height, image_width, grayed_image);
    
  return 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `.bmp` files, the pixel data for a row must be aligned [upward] to a multiple of 4.

This is *not* padding between *pixels*. It is *alignment* between *rows*.

The number of *bytes*  between rows is known as the *stride*:

```
int bytes_per_pixel = 3;  // number of bytes for 8 bit RGB pixels
int alignment = 4;  // required byte alignment for BMP image rows
int width = ...;  // number of pixels / row

// number of bytes in a row (round _up_ by alignment)
int stride = (width * bytes_per_pixel) + (alignment - 1);
stride /= alignment;
stride *= alignment;
```

In `read_bmp_data`, after your first `for` loop (for `i`), add an `fseek`. This will seek to the disk data for row `i` (i.e. it handles row padding/alignment):

```
for (int i = height - 1; i > 0; i = i - 1) {
    fseek(image, i * stride, SEEK_SET);

    for (int j = 0; j < width; j = j + 1) {
        fread(pixel, 3, 1, image);
        int gray_scale_value = grayScaleConversion(pixel);
        converted_image[i][j] = gray_scale_value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Padding is not per pixel; it is per row of pixels.

This means that each row of pixels must have a length which is a multiple of 4.

There is no such thing as stopping before the padded bytes.

What you want to do is to read an entire row of pixels, as you are already doing, and then advance by as many bytes as necessary in order to skip the padding, before starting to read the next row.

So, first, you need to calculate how many bytes of padding there are. That would be `int padding = (width * 3) % 4`.

Since you are using `fread()`, then after the end of the `j` loop and before the end of the `i` loop you will need to use `fseek()` to skip `padding`
bytes.

As you will find out later on, reading an image pixel by pixel using `fread()` is ***preposterously slow***, so you should first read the entire image into memory, and then use a pointer to read pixels from memory, but that's a different story.

Comment: It's not `(width * 3) % 4`. For example, if `width` is 3, that gives `9%4 = 1` when the padding should be 3.

Comment: @user3386109 `3 - (width * 3 - 1) % 4`

Comment: @user3386109 oh. You are probably right.

Comment: @dimich oh. You are probably right.

Comment: @dimich That works. I usually do what the other answer suggests. Compute the line stride by rounding `width * 3` up to a multiple of 4, and then `fread` an entire line at a time. That gives a decent balance between performance and memory usage.